# Prove there are infinitely many *primitive* solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = z^4$

Tags: number-theory

For x, y, z $\in \mathbb N $ where $\gcd(x,y) = 1$

These solutions must also be primitive.

If we let $ w = z^2 $ so that $ x^2 + y^2 = w^2$

I have that for r, s $\in \mathbb N$  where $\gcd(r, s) = 1$ (coprime),
with opposite parity:

Let $ x = r^2 - s^2\\
     y = 2rs \\
    w = r^2 + s^2 $

Now for $t, u \in \mathbb N$ where $\gcd(t, u) = 1$ (coprime),
with opposite parity:

let $ r = t^2 - u^2\\
       s = 2tu\\
        z = t^2 + u^2 $

Where $r,s,z$ are coprimes with $r$ odd and $s$ even (by definition).

So we have:
$ x = ( t^2 - u^2)^2 -(2tu)^2\\
y = 2( t^2 - u^2)(2tu)\\
w = z^2 = ( t^2 - u^2)^2 + (2tu)^2 $

Hence $x, y$ and $z^2 $ is a primitive solution.

Any mistakes here?

Comment: yep it's similar, but I require a rigorous proof of which I am stuck on.

Comment: You don't get a primitive solution for all pairs $t,u$. You must have $t,u$ coprime, and one of them even, the other odd. Then you get coprimes $r,s$ (and $z$), with $r$ odd and $s$ even. That then produces a primitive solution of $x^2+y^2 = z^4$.

Comment: I understand this, but then I am unsure where I am wrong in my proof?

Comment: @jakey The issue with your proof, is that it is not clear why $x, y, w$ are coprime, and they do not need to be, for all pairs of coprime $(t,u)$. For example, if $t, u$ are both odd, then all your values are a multiple of 2.

Comment: @DanielFischer and CalvinLin I have amended the proof, is this what you are both referring too?

Comment: @CalvinLin see above

Comment: @jakey, the proof now looks correct. but you are using a fact that $\gcd(t,u) = 1 \wedge t \ne u \pmod 2 \implies \gcd(t^2-u^2,2tu) = 1 \wedge t^2 - u^2 \ne 2tu \pmod 2$. It is true but it is not that obvious.

Comment: what does the upward arrow ^ mean in your notation?

Comment: as i'm currently trying to work out why $gcd(t^2 - u^2, 2tu) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Notice

$$\begin{cases}
X(t) = t^4 - 6t^2 + 1\\
Y(t) = 4t(t^2-1)\\
Z(t) = t^2+1
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ satisfy }\quad X(t)^2 + Y(t)^2 = Z(t)^4
$$

and the algebraic identity

$$(1-320t^2)X(16t) + (1280t^2 - 29)t Y(16t) = 1$$

implies $X(16t)$ and $Y(16t)$ are relative prime for any integer $t$
as long as neither $X(16t)$ nor $Y(16t)$ vanish.

Since $X(16t)$ and $Y(16t)$ have only finitely many roots, we have infinite many primitive solutions of the original equation in the form $(x,y,z) = (X(16t),Y(16t),Z(16t)$. 
For example,

$$\begin{array}{rcrcl}
t = 1 &\quad\longrightarrow\quad& 64001^2 + 16320^2 &=& 257^4\\
t = 2 &\quad\longrightarrow\quad& 1042433^2 + 130944^2 &=& 1025^2\\
t = 3 &\quad\longrightarrow\quad& 5294593^2 + 442176^2 &=& 2305^2
\end{array}$$

**Note**

The $X(t), Y(t)$ and $Z(t)$ here is really a special case of the parametrization
given in the question. We have fixed the parameter $u$ there to be $1$. 
It is easy to verify $$\gcd(X(t),Y(t)) = 1\quad\text{ as a polynomial over }\mathbb{Q}$$
Equivalently, this means there are $m(t), n(t) \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$ such that
$$m(t) X(t) + n(t) Y(t) = 1$$
What I'm doing is filling the last gap in the question. I choose $t$ in such a way to force $m(t)$ and $n(t)$ to be integers. This turn the solution given in question to a primitive one.

Comment: Thank you for this it's helpful. But how did you choose $m(t)$ and $n(t)$? $(1 - 320t^2)$ and $(1280t^2 - 29)$ seem so random? and how did out $X(t)$ become $X(16t)$ ?

Comment: @jakey, you can obtain $m(t), n(t)$ by Euclidean algorithm on polynomials. Once you compute that, you will find the coefficients of $m(t),n(t)$ has 16 as their common denominator. Replacing $t$ by $16t$ will clear that denominator and give you a pair of integer polynomials.

Comment: that's perfect, thank you. However i still require that my proof above is correct and complete. This shows me how to give examples very nicely though! :)