# Are there any two positive integers such that the square root of the sum of their squares give a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory

Are there two positive integers $$ \text{{ (x,y) | $ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = z $  }}$$
where $ z$ is a perfect square.

Comment: do you mean to say $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z^2$?

Comment: Yes, the question in the title and the question in the body do not agree.

Comment: The values $7^2+24^2=5^4$ gives a solution to both possible questions.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172539/prove-that-x2-y2-z4-has-infinitely-many-solutions-with-x-y-z-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for integers such that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z$, then there's plenty, for example, $3,4,5$ or $12,5,13$.
If you're looking for integers such that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=c^2$, then take any solutions to the first equation and multiply everything by $z$, e.g. take $3,4,5$ and multiply by $5$.
Then, since
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z,$$
it follows that
$$\sqrt{(xz)^2+(yz)^2}=\sqrt{z^2(x^2+y^2)}$$
$$=z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z^2$$

For example, $15^2+20^2=25^2$.